# Boostrap Accordion cannot collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Recently, I am building a new project using bootstrap accordion. When I click the heading, at first I will add some extra content into panel and then open the panel and close other panels. But when I add the extra content and invoke `.collapse('show')` function, other accordion element doesn't close. Can somebody explain the reason?  Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Accordion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!--<button id="item1">item1</button>-->
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" id="item1" role="button" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#item1').click(function() {
        $('#collapseOne').append(`
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>asdfsdf</p>
            <p>sdafweff</p>
            <p>dsafsdaf</p>
            <p>dsafwer</p>
          </div>
        `);
        $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding `href="#collapseOne"` to the anchor with id `item1` will fix that problem. You want to append that markup each time you click on `#item1`?

Comment: You don't need `$('collapseOne').collapse('show');` here's a working codepen for you to review http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/KNpaxv

Comment: First step is append element to the `.panel` and then show the `.panel` and close other opening `.panel`.

Comment: Are all panels closed to begin with? I don't get it. Adding `href="#collapseOne"` triggers a collapse/expand on each click per bootstrap.js

Comment: If you want to add the extra content on show, you should use `$('#item1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() { ... });`

Comment: When I click `#item1`, the heading of first panel, I append some elements to `#collapseOne` and then expand it with sliding animation. I think I should append elements at first and then trigger expanding.